# how to get data from 2 fields json in table css

Tags: php, json, database, phpmyadmin

hi sir sorry i want to ask again

how to if get 2 fields in json?

if 1 fields, like this :

```
$json = json_decode($row['orders'], true);  // 2nd argument `true` converts json object into array.
$email = $json['email'];
```

and then add this :

```
<td>'.$json["email"].'</td>
```

how to get 2 fields from json sir, i mean like this

fields 1 : Orders

```
========
orders
======== 
{email":"tst@gmail.com","name":"myname","phone":"+123123123"}
```

fields 2 : Country

```
=========
country
=========
[{id":"001","country:"english","code:"123123"}]
```

see the country fields diferent code from orders fields

in order fields have code {}

and in counrty fields have code [{}]

i try like this not work :

```
$json_orders = json_decode($row['orders'], true);
$email = $json_orders['email'];
$json_country = json_decode($row['country'], true);
$country = $json_country['country'];
```

and then this in table css :

```
<td>'.$json['email'].'</td>

<td>'.$json['country'].'</td>
```

how to get data from 2 fields in json sir?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json input data is malformed because there are several missing double quotes.

Specifically, `email` and `id` need a double quote before them and `country` and `code` need a double quote immediately after.

Initially, I assumed that this was a code posting error, but if this is the problem in your actual project, then something is not generating valid json strings.  If you are building these strings, I hope you are converting arrays using `json_encode()` and not trying to write these quasi-json strings manually with concatenation.

If you fix your json strings, you can decode and access the data like this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GpBZQ))

```
$row['orders'] = '{"email":"tst@gmail.com","name":"myname","phone":"+123123123"}';  // assoc array
$row['country'] = '[{"id":"001","country":"english","code":"123123"}]';  // indexed array containing an assoc array

$json_orders = json_decode($row['orders'], true);
echo $json_orders['email'];
echo "\n---\n";
$json_country = json_decode($row['country'], true);
echo $json_country[0]['country'];
```

Output:

```
tst@gmail.com
---
english
```

*Note, that `$row['country']` has a different structure (multi-dimensional) than `$row['orders']`, so you will have to access the first level with `[0]`.

Comment: hi sir, thanks for reply
i try its work, but the output not full text "english" just show "e" 
how to full show text "english" sir?

Comment: Then you have supplied us with inaccurate input data.  Without seeing the real json string, I could spend an hour making blind guesses.

Comment: works sir, i wrong copy code
thank you sir for help me